# Почему длинное слово выходит за границы блока?

Tags: html, css

Почему контент выходит за пределы div'a `num-box` ?

```css
.num-box {
  margin-top: 75px;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<div class="num-box">
eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
</div>
```

Пример на [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kq9m8fth/)

Comment: а почему он не должен выходить за границы? :-)

Comment: так как это одно слово, используйте word-wrap: break-word; http://htmlbook.ru/css/word-wrap. Пример - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/8r7p6m70/

Comment: soledar10, спасибо, помогли!

Answer (score 12):

Это одно слово. По умолчанию оно не разбивается на части внутри блока.
Сначала ссылка на [**спецификацию**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#line-breaking).
Теперь мой примерный перевод:

> В большинстве систем письменности при отсутствии явных переносов
>   система мягких переносов срабатывает только на границах слов.   Многие
>   из этих систем используют пробелы и знаки препинания, чтобы явно
>   разграничить слова. Возможность мягкого переноса может быть определена
>   по этим признакам.

---

Исправить можно несколькими способами:

## Мягкий перенос

Лучше всего указать браузерам, как переносить длинные слова, не полагаясь на автоматические средства. Сделать это можно с помощью мягкого переноса.
Чтобы набрать его можно использовать мнемонику `&shy;` (`&#173;`) или ввести <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>0173</kbd> на клавиатуре (цифры набирать по одной, не отпуская <kbd>alt</kbd>).

**Внимание:** невозможно использование более 5 мягких переносов в одном слове.
Проверено в последней бете Yandex.Browser.

```css
.num-box {
  margin-top: 75px; /* для демонстрации */
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  padding: 5px; /* для демонстрации */
}
```

```html
<div class="num-box">
eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee&shy;eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee&shy;eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee&shy;eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee&shy;eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee&shy;eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
</div>
```

---

## Пробел с нулевой длиной

> [`ZERO-WIDTH SPACE`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB#.D0.94.D1.80.D1.83.D0.B3.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B1.D0.B5.D0.BB.D1.8B_.D0.B2_.D0.AE.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B5) — показывает места, в которых можно разрывать строку,
>   не добавляя знак переноса; ширина его нулевая.   Применяется в языках,
>   в которых пробелов нет. При выравнивании текста по ширине может
>   расширяться, как и любой другой пробел.

Ввести можно используя `&#8203;` или `&#x200B`.

**Внимание:** невозможно использование более 5 пробелов нулевой длины в одном слове.
Проверено в последней бете Yandex.Browser.

```css
.num-box {
  margin-top: 75px; /* для демонстрации */
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  padding: 5px; /* для демонстрации */
}
```

```html
<div class="num-box">
eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee&#8203;eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee&#8203;eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee&#8203;eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee&#8203;eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee&#8203;eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
</div>
```

---

## Элемент [`<wbr>`](http://htmlbook.ru/html/wbr)

> Тег `<wbr>` указывает браузеру место, где допускается делать перенос
>   строки в тексте, если этого требует ширина родительского элемента.

**Внимание:** невозможно использование более 5 элементов `<wbr>` в одном слове.
Проверено в последней бете Yandex.Browser.

```css
.num-box {
  margin-top: 75px; /* для демонстрации */
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  padding: 5px; /* для демонстрации */
}
```

```html
<div class="num-box">
eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee<wbr>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee<wbr>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee<wbr>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee<wbr>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee<wbr>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
</div>
```

---

## CSS-свойство [`word-wrap`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/word-wrap)

> Свойство `word-wrap` указывает, переносить или нет длинные слова,
>   которые не помещаются по ширине в заданную область. Данное свойство
>   носит черновой характер и при валидации документа на CSS3 выдает
>   ошибку.

> `break-word` — Перенос строк добавляется автоматически, чтобы слово
>   поместилось в заданную ширину блока.

```css
.num-box {
  margin-top: 75px; /* для демонстрации */
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding: 5px; /* для демонстрации */
}
```

```html
<div class="num-box">
eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
</div>
```

---

## CSS-свойство [`overflow`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/overflow)

> Свойство `overflow` управляет отображением содержания блочного элемента,
>   если оно целиком не помещается и выходит за область заданных размеров.

> `auto` — Полосы прокрутки добавляются только при необходимости.

```css
.num-box {
  margin-top: 75px; /* для демонстрации */
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 5px; /* для демонстрации */
}
```

```html
<div class="num-box">
eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
</div>
```

При ответе использована информация из ответов к вопросу: "[How to prevent long words from breaking my div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320184/how-to-prevent-long-words-from-breaking-my-div)"

Comment: w3c решили назвать `word-wrap` иначе - `overflow-wrap`. Хотя браузеры лучше едят старое название. http://caniuse.com/#feat=wordwrap

Comment: @Qwertiy, думаю, пока рано обновлять ответ, судя по поддержке, но спасибо за это замечание

Answer (score 2):

```css
.num-box {
  margin-top: 75px;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  /* word-break: break-word; /* webkit only */
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word; /* word-wrap по спецификации так называется */
}
```

```html
<div class="num-box">
eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
</div>
```

Comment: Firefox 44.0.1 - одна строка без переносов. Вы в каком браузере проверяли свой ответ?

Comment: Скорее всего у вас опечатка - не `word-break: break-word;`, а `word-wrap: break-word;`

Comment: @MiKeBu, http://caniuse.com/#feat=word-break Но в FF действительно не работает...

Comment: @MiKeBu, ответ обновлён.

Comment: [`word-break: normal | keep-all | break-all`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#word-break) и [`word-wrap: normal | break-word`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#overflow-wrap) Похожий функционал и похожие имена, просто было перепутано соответствие свойств и значений (гиперболизированно: цвет - px, размер - rgb)

Comment: @MiKeBu, по ссылке на caniuse про word-break: "Chrome, Safari and other WebKit/Blink browsers also support the unofficial break-word value which is treated like word-wrap: break-word".