# Как сделать поведение переносов строк в div аналогичным поведению в textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть `textarea` в которую вручную вбивается текст, после чего можно нажать кнопку и данные выводятся в `div` блоке. Все переносы строк отступы и т.д. переносятся без проблем.
Реализовано с помощью `elem.value.replace(/(\n|\r)+/g, '<br>');`.

Проблема заключается в том, что если в `textarea` написать длинное неразрывное слово или просто набор символов, но без пробелов, то в `textarea` текст автоматически переноситься на другую строку при достижении края поля, а при переносе в `div` этот перенос не сохраняется и содержимое вылезает за пределы блока.

Как сделать так, чтобы эти переносы строк отображались в `div`?

Comment: указать одинаковый шрифт в textarea и div, +одинаковую ширину блока, + авто перенос содержимого по средствам **css** и все  должно получится более одинаковым.

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, пример, воспроизводящий вашу проблему (соберите сниппет)

Comment: @Vladimir Ch ответил на мой вопрос, добавил в css автоматически перенос содержимого и помогло, до это не знал о такой возможности и не нашел в интернете.

Comment: @VladimirCh оформите в виде ответа

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему длинное слово выходит за границы блока?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/493398/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Comment: Хм.. Или всё-таки не закрывать как дубликат?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  document.querySelector("div").textContent = document.querySelector("textarea").value;
})
```

```css
textarea, div {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1rem;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: .5em;
}

textarea {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  height: 7em;
}

div {
  white-space: pre-line;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<textarea autofocus></textarea>
<div></div>
```