# Автоперенос строк

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Скачал скрипт jodit editor (http://xdsoft.net/jodit/)

Решил проверить на перенос строки. Написал непрерывно букву *a*, но оно, вместо переноса, уезжает вправо. Притом, что на сайте работает нормально

Вот мой код:

```js
$(document).ready(function (){ 
  $(".myButton").click(function (){
    $("body").animate({"scrollTop":0},"fast");
 $("body").css("overflow","hidden");
  });
  $(".overlay, .close_window").click(function (){
    $("body").css("overflow","auto");
  });
  var editor = new Jodit('#editor', {
      buttons: ['bold', 'italic', '|', 'ul', 'ol', '|', 'font', 'fontsize', 'brush', 'paragraph', '|','image', 'video', 'table', 'link', '|', 'left', 'center', 'right', 'justify', '|', 'undo', 'redo', '|', 'hr', 'eraser'],
      buttonsMD: ['bold', 'italic', '|', 'ul', 'ol', '|', 'font', 'fontsize', 'brush', 'paragraph', '|','image', 'video', 'table', 'link', '|', 'left', 'center', 'right', 'justify', '|', 'undo', 'redo', '|', 'hr', 'eraser'],
      buttonsXS: ['bold', 'italic', '|', 'ul', 'ol', '|', 'font', 'fontsize', 'brush', 'paragraph', '|','image', 'video', 'table', 'link', '|', 'left', 'center', 'right', 'justify', '|', 'undo', 'redo', '|', 'hr', 'eraser']
   });
   var editor = new Jodit('#editor2', {
      buttons: ['bold', 'italic', '|', 'ul', 'ol', '|', 'font', 'fontsize', 'brush', 'paragraph', '|','image', 'video', 'table', 'link', '|', 'left', 'center', 'right', 'justify', '|', 'undo', 'redo', '|', 'hr', 'eraser'],
      buttonsMD: ['bold', 'italic', '|', 'ul', 'ol', '|', 'font', 'fontsize', 'brush', 'paragraph', '|','image', 'video', 'table', 'link', '|', 'left', 'center', 'right', 'justify', '|', 'undo', 'redo', '|', 'hr', 'eraser'],
      buttonsXS: ['bold', 'italic', '|', 'ul', 'ol', '|', 'font', 'fontsize', 'brush', 'paragraph', '|','image', 'video', 'table', 'link', '|', 'left', 'center', 'right', 'justify', '|', 'undo', 'redo', '|', 'hr', 'eraser']
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jodit/2.5.62/jodit.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jodit/2.5.62/jodit.min.js"></script>

<textarea rows='4' id='editor' name='post'></textarea>
<textarea rows='4' id='editor2' name='text'></textarea>
```

Comment: @Yuri Извините ошыбка, исправил

Comment: Сейчас я попрыгаю с бубном и сразу появится решение. Покажите ваш код, желательно, что бы он тут открывался)

Comment: @Yuri не могу скинуть код (очень его много н сайте, все в одном файле если вы про css)

Comment: Нет, мне желательно ваш скрипт и html. Как вы его подключаете. А то вам сейчас минусов натыкают)

Comment: хорошо щяс скину как я подключаюсь

Comment: Простите конечно, но всё работает

Comment: Я бы ещё вместо второго `var editor` использовал бы переменную с другим именем.

Comment: @Yuri а у меня на сайте - нет

Comment: @BedOmar, может вы где в стилях указали, что бы строка не переносилась?

Comment: а каким кодом это можно сделать, поищу

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему длинное слово выходит за границы блока?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/493398/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Answer (score 3):

Я сам нашел (я автор вопроса) и надеюсь помоч другим мне помогло это: `word-break: break-all;`

Comment: Ну хорошо тогда. Отметь свой вопрос, как решение :)

Comment: Т.е. вопрос никакого отношения к плагину не имеет?